# Google Distance API Invalid Key

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I'm just starting to use Google Maps APIs and I'm having some trouble when attempting to send a request via Postman to

```
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix?<params>&key="key value"]
```

I've created an API Key in the Google Maps Console and I'm sending the key along with origins and destinations values however each time I attempt to send the request I'm receiving:

```
{
"destination_addresses": [],
"error_message": "The provided API key is invalid. ",
"origin_addresses": [],
"rows": [],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

}

Now the odd thing is that I can call the Distance API using just fine.  The results I receive from a call to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?<params>&key="key value"
```

returns a valid response.

I've checked and double checked the API key value and I'm sure it's being sent and it's the only key that I have generated.
Anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting google we determined that the problem is not with the request but with the JSON exported from the google maps api/Postman collection.
Changing the Authorization to none and manually adding the key as a parameter in a request corrected the issue.